# AWS $_POST is empty with REST API. Site is working fine

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on REST APIs of `cakephp`. All working good on my localhost. When I transfer code to live server which is `AWS EC2 Ubuntu` machine suddenly all stop working. While my site is working fine.

on debug I found that `$_POST` is empty.

here is my code

```
   public function add() { //die('dsafs');
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->layout = false;
     //   $this->loadModel('User');
        $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
        pr($entityBody);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->validates($this->request->data)) {
                if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                    $response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Thank you for registering with us. Please check your e-mail inbox as your e-mail confirmation has just been sent.');
                } else {
                    $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'There might be some error. Please try again');
                }
            } else {
                $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => array_values($this->User->validationErrors));
            }
            echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($response), ENT_NOQUOTES));
            //  print_r($response);
        }else{
            echo "you are not authorised";
        }
        exit();
    }
```

I allowed my controller in **AppController.php**

```
   function beforeFilter() {
        //pr($this->params);die;
        if (in_array($this->params['controller'], array('api'))) {
            // For RESTful web service requests, we check the name of our contoller
            $this->Auth->allow();
            // this line should always be there to ensure that all rest calls are secure
//             $this->Security->requireSecure(); 
//             $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('edit', 'delete', 'add', 'view');
        } else {
            $this->_defaultSettings();
        }
    }
```

and add routing too in **routes.php**

```
Router::mapResources('api');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Below is the response I am getting.

```
 <pre></pre>you are not authorised
```

[image]

let me know if you need any thing else.

Comment: Please post the client side javascript code. Also, what version of PHP you are running on your development and live server.

Comment: I am using `postman` extension of chrome for sending data. and both local and live running on php5.6

Comment: I see. Please post the Body Content Type, the key=>value pairs and any other headers you are setting in postman.

Comment: It seems legit. The last one, any chances of seeing the Core section returned by phpinfo() in your live server?

Comment: Any luck on being able to print your phpinfo()? The core section would help.

Comment: What do you need to check? I will update the answer with that.

Comment: There are a few things that need to be checked, but don't worry. I'm going to attempt an answer, but before please post the output of `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: `<pre></pre>` is the output. and BTW my site is working fine. all operations are working.

Comment: I need the output of `file_get_contents("php://input")`when you submit your post data with postman

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_get_contents('php://input') for taking data from AJAX request. But if you want to send data from POSTMAN then you need to use $_POST to take that data.